# ffmpeg: How can I add video-1 at the beginning of video-2

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I want to add video-1 at the beginning of video-2  with command line in linux, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `ffmpeg -i input.flv output.mpg` to convert video format to `mpg`,
then run `cat *.mpg > all.mpg`

Comment: Maybe I should remove files metadata and then try... but this way it didn't work